# Correct way to batch render Rmarkdown files for use with Hugo

Tags: r-markdown, hugo, kable, blogdown

I am trying to render a bunch of `.html` pages from `.Rmd` by using `rmarkdown::render()` on a template `.Rmd` and pass it some variable through a loop.

```
for (i in some_vector){
  rmarkdown::render(my_template.Rmd,
                    output_format = "html_document",
                    output_file = ... ,
                    output_dir = ... )
}
```

The template is set up to expect the variable and renders fine. However, other .Rmd pages in other parts of the site no longer render properly if I generate my `.html` files then run `blogdown::serve_site()`

The .html files rendered by blogdown::serve_site() seem to have incorrect headers and missing html parts when rendered automatically by blogdown. The generated html page still retains the yaml header components at the top of the file.

Eg:

```
---
title = 
date = 
layout = 
author =
---
```

If I don't batch generate my files, and simply run serve_site() on the existing site files then I get no issue. My suspicion is that running rmarkdown::render() changes some session parameter, but I have no idea. My aim is to create the necessary pages myself and then have blogdown render the rest upon serve_site().

Does anyone have any idea what the issue is?

Comment: I just define a `.bashrc` command to do this in batch mode: `serveSite() { Rscript -e "blogdown::serve_site()"; }` and type `serveSite` at the command prompt.

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure how this addresses my issue? Maybe I'm not understanding properly? I'm using blogdown through Rstudio, but either way I'm having issues with blogdown::serve_site() and rmarkdown::render() conflicting in some way and causing the rendered pages to look different when they are both ran.

Comment: I just find that running `serveSite` separately gets automatic creation of any child file when the corresponding parent changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, I worked out how to generate the correct file outputs. My issue was borne of an ignorance of how blogdown works.

Essentially, when serving site, blogdown does the following:

1. Locate `.Rmd` files
2. Covert to `.html` files formatted for HUGO
3. HUGO serves the final `.html` file to its location in `/public`

What I was doing was skipping these steps and creating a final rendered `.html` file through `rmarkdown::render()` thus creating files that were incompatible with the theming actions carried out by HUGO before serving the final `.html`.

Instead of manually rendering `.Rmd` files through a loop and passing it variables, I edit lines of the template and write the output as individual `.Rmd` files:

```
file.src <- file("~/R/sample_proforma_2.Rmd", 
                 open = "r")
file.lines <- readLines(file.src)
rmd.list <- list()
for(i in c("sample_117" ,"sample_118", "sample_119", "sample_121")){
  tmp.lines <- file.lines
  tmp.lines[4] <- gsub("empty\\+title", gsub("_", " ", toupper(i)), tmp.lines[4])
  tmp.lines[6] <- gsub("empty\\+title", gsub("_", " ", toupper(i)), tmp.lines[6])
  tmp.lines[9] <- gsub("empty\\+circos", toupper(i), tmp.lines[9])
  tmp.lines[15] <- gsub("empty\\+maf", i, tmp.lines[15])
  tmp.lines[21] <- gsub("empty\\+tag", i, c("- CIRCOS\n- MAF"))
  rmd.list[[i]] <- tmp.lines
}

for (i in names(rmd.list)){
  write.table(rmd.list[[i]],
              paste0("~/content/sample/",i,".Rmd"),
              sep = "",
              quote = FALSE,
              col.names = FALSE,
              row.names = FALSE)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have struggled hours with the same problem. I want to generate thousands of separate pages (with R, Blogdown and Hugo) out of ~10 templates and script everything.

Here is what seems to work:

1. Have your custom R/build.R to generate the *markdown* (.md) pages in a loop.
2. Have Hugo to convert the markdown (.md) file to HTML
3. Use knitr::knit, not rmarkdown:render, to process the Rmarkdown templates (.Rmd) to markdown (.md)
4. The only way to get images into right places with the right relative URLs using knit() is to a) set `output = 'dest/dir/file_name.md'`, b) use `fig.path='figure'` (or whatever you like) AND c) move the `fig.path` directory under the `dest/dir/figure` after every single `knit()`.

Otherwise `knit()` either puts the images under `ROOT/figure` or creates a relative image links into the .md file like `dest/dir/figure/plot.png` for a page that is already under `dest/dir/`.

My `R/build.R`.

```
updates <- c( '6.3', '6.4', '6.5');
library('knitr')

dir.create(file.path('content/', 'update'), showWarnings = FALSE);

for (update in updates) {
  dir_name <- paste0('content/update/', update);
  dir.create(file.path(dir_name), showWarnings = FALSE);
  knit(input = 'R/update.rmd', output = paste0(dir_name, '/_index.md'));
  ## THIS IS REQUIRED AFTER EVERY knit()!!! 
  ## otherwise the image links go wrong and/or the next knit() may overwrite the previous plots

  file.rename('figure', paste0(dir_name, '/figure'));    
}
```

and `R/update.rmd`:

````
---
title: Version `r update`
date: `r Sys.Date()`
author: Jylpah
output: md_document
---
This is a test. Version is `r update`. 

```{r, plot, echo=FALSE, fig.path='figure/'}
A <- sample(10,50,replace = TRUE);
hist(A);
```

## Something else

Another plot

```{r, plot_another, echo=FALSE, fig.path='figure/'}
B <- sample(10,50,replace = TRUE);
hist(B);
```
````

I hope the above is somehow understandable and helps you and others.

Comment: Hi, if you see in my own answer above, I do something slightly different. I have an `.Rmd` template I read in using `readLines()` and in a loop I replace the code I need to. Then I just write the product of each loop out as a separate `.Rmd` file. This avoids having to faff on with `knitr::knit()` and `rmarkdown:render()` and just generates documents ready for Hugo to render.

It's not the most elegant solution, but it works for me.

Comment: Hi, I saw your approach, but did not it that elegant nor flexible in case different pages  have different front matter etc. Just wanted to post my solution for others struggling with the same issue.